# SQL Query to find records between dates and times

Tags: sql-server-2008

Good morning,

I need to find all records between two dates, but need to include all records from 8 days ago from the date the query is executed, up to 17:00 on the previous day that the query is executed.

So running it Thursday 20th would show me all records on the 13th from midnight, to 17:00 on the 19th.

I originally had getdate()-x for them both but can't work out how to get the hour part included for the previous day.

Look forward to your suggestions.

Comment: Please include some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

Try this

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,  DATEADD(day, -1, '2013-03-13 00:00:00.000'), GETDATE())

OR

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,  DATEADD(day, -1, @CreatedDate), GETDATE())

Comment: The first returns The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value, the second returns '1' as a value.